# Customer login not working after removing extension Magento 2 / Eway

Tags: magento2, extensions, token

I have removed a payment gateway extension - eway-rapid-magento2 - from my Magento 2.4.2 store. The site was working correctly before I removed this extension, now I am getting this logged error:

Class Eway\EwayRapid\Model\Customer\Token\Backend does not exist at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:24

when trying to use the customer login on the front end. (The log in is not successful)

To remove the extension, I did the following:
Disabled all Eway modules
Ran

- setup:upgrade
- setup:static-content:deploy -f

Tested at this point - it was working correctly.

Then I did this:
composer remove eway/eway-rapid-magento2 (this was successful)

- setup:upgrade
- setup:di:compile
- setup:static-content:deploy -f

At this point, the customer login no longer works and the error message above gets logged. So I tried:
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/*
then

- setup:static-content:deploy -f
  again. But still the same error.

Can anyone give me advice about how to fix this? It's not a problem in ClassReader function. It must be in the function that calls ClassReader. I tried turning on template path hints to try and get a clue of what that funciton might be, but that hasn't helped me figure it out.

Any ideas, clues or pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this path is issue , and it is store in your database ,so error occurs ,
Find this in your Magento database in all tables.& Delete those entries.

```
Eway\EwayRapid\Model\Customer\Token\Backend
```

Comment: you can search also for this path "Eway\EwayRapid" only those world

Comment: It was in the eav_attribute table.